# "program_invocation_name" not compiled under MacOS

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Trying to print the program name using **program_invocation_name**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  extern char *program_invocation_name;
  printf("%s \n", program_invocation_name);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Using the command **gcc filename.c -o filename**, the above code works in Linux, but NOT compiled under MacOS:

```
gcc filename.c -o filename
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_program_invocation_name", referenced from:
  _main in filename-4acad8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

`program_invocation_name` is not part of any standard; it's an extension provided by glibc and a few other systems; MacOS isn't one of them. Using it like you're doing here is gratuitously non-portable and pointless. Just use `argv[0]`.

The only point of `program_invocation_name` is for functions which aren't `main` and don't have any contract for `main` to pass `argv[0]` to them or otherwise make it available to get the (initial) value of `argv[0]`.

Comment: Correct, but note that this is not useless. If you are creating an independent library, this makes it possible to get the program name. Otherwise it means "here is our library, but you have to modify your code to use it".

Answer (score 0):

From [Glibc Function Substitutes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Glibc-Function-Substitutes.html#Glibc-Function-Substitutes) under [12.14 Glibc Extensions to errno.h](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Glibc-errno_002eh.html#Glibc-errno_002eh):

> 12.14.1 `program_invocation_name`
>
> Portability problems not fixed by Gnulib:
>
> This variable is missing on some platforms: Mac OS X 10.5, FreeBSD 6.0, NetBSD 5.0, OpenBSD 3.8, Minix 3.1.8, AIX 5.1, HP-UX 11, IRIX 6.5, OSF/1 5.1, Solaris 11.4, Cygwin 1.7.7, mingw, MSVC 14, Interix 3.5, Android 9.0.